# Why isn't there any packages folder in my .NET Core solution's containing folder?

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package-restore

Are packages now cached in a more shared location somewhere or what?

My solution folder is devoid of any `packages` folder:

[image: Solution folder without packages folder]

Comment: Oh, I ever so sarcastically wonder what that downvote was for, just after I added more information to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 75):

Per project: References->Nuget dictates what packages are referenced and restored. But, as Eastrall mentioned, the packages folder is now global and located in your user folder: `C:\Users\[YourUsername]\.nuget\packages`

Comment: Again such a bad architectural decision from Microsoft - we kind of back to GAC :( - instead of container approach...

Comment: It's an interesting approach, for sure. Not as bad as GAC, the idea was that your PC/user can cache the collection of packages referenced across many projects and solutions.  It's a storage-saving enhancement. Its actually helpful if you work in many projects. There's no "run-time resolution", they just consolidated package folders into one package folder at the user-level.

Comment: True - but another side of the coin dev and prod (deployed) are different - I'll bet on it that there would be some issues... :) - I'd love to opt it in or opt it out - that would be gr8! For sure there are following advantages:

Comment: 1. Less load on the nuget server. 2. Less local space consumption. 3. Build time optimization - no copying any nugets to bin folder.

Comment: @GeorgeAnisimov Dev and prod will not be different as long as you use '--self-contained true' with dotnet publish on the build server. I do this as part of creating deployment-packages.

Comment: In case where some content needed to be copied from the package folder (as a build activity may be), its best to have the content relative to the sln. In that case, @CJBS [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880839/1764696) will work better.

Comment: @GeorgeAnisimov anyway it's an improvement over packages folder

Answer (score 51):

### To force ./packages folder for Solution

To force download of packages folder to be a child of the solution folder for .NET Core projects, follow these steps:

1. Create a `NuGet.Config` file in the same directory as the `.sln` file.
2. Copy the following contents into the  `NuGet.Config` file:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <configuration>
>   <config>
>     <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=".\packages" />
>   </config>
> </configuration>
> ```

3. Configure NuGet to download missing packages by:

   3.1. In Visual Studio: `Tools -> Options`

   3.2. Filter by `nuget` (top left in dialog). Select `General`

   3.3. Ensure `Allow NuGet to download missing packages` is checked

[image]

3. Close and re-open the solution. NuGet will download the required packages.

---

Note: the NuGet.Config configuration can also be achieved by executing the following command from the NuGet Package Manager Console (`Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console`):

```
PM> nuget config -set globalPackagesFolder=.\packages -configfile "$(pwd)\NuGet.Config"
```

Comment: I had a little more work - had to add nuget.org api address

<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=".\packages" />
  </config>

  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

Comment: God Tier answer. Fixed my intranet deployment issues.

Comment: be aware of the NUGET_PACKAGES env variable overriding this setting 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file

Answer (score 15):

You still have `packages` folder in your .NET Core solution, but the global packages are located at: `C:\Users\[YourUsername]\.nuget\packages`

Answer (score 11):

You can check out a question I asked to see if the answers do you any good.

[How do I include NuGet packages in my solution for .Net Core projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687058/how-do-i-include-nuget-packages-in-my-solution-for-net-core-projects)

You can get that packages folder back, but you might not be happy with the results, since .Net Core projects rely on so many NuGet packages.  Mine is hovering around 1 GB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file#config-section

Comment: However. if you are using also git you could add the packages folder to the git ignore file