# Can new projects in VS2017 store nuget packages in project packages director?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

Through automatic nuget restore is convenient it is not safe. I previously checked in all packages into the repository. This was easy as VS created a packages directory under the project root.

Now I find I have a

```
~/.nuget
```

directory outside the project hierarchy. Is there a way to revert the behavior? Perhaps a flag in the `*.csproj` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include NuGet packages in my solution for .Net Core projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687058/how-do-i-include-nuget-packages-in-my-solution-for-net-core-projects)

Comment: Ah sry, it isn't really

Comment: I'm not aware of NuGet restore being "unsafe", in fact my experience is the opposite - checking in packages can lead to build issues if the package contents are not correctly added (e.g. dlls are excluded). NuGet [caches packages locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-nuget-cache) so offline restore should work just fine as long as you have download the package once.

Comment: Unsafe in that if I have to rebuild from source in 15 years time to debug a customer installation I don't want to find that the particular version of the nuget package I was relying on has disappeared from the Nuget gallery or that the nuget gallery doesn't exist anymore. Some companies have such support contracts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the location for the global package folder to a solution-local location by specifying a path in a `NuGet.Config` file next to the solution (note that you have to re-open the solution for this to have an effect):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=".\packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

There are two properties that can be set this way to affect the location of where the packages will be restored to. `repositoryPath` for `packages.config` projects and `globalPackagesFolder` for `project.json` and projects using`PackageReference`.