# How can I use msbuild without project.assets.json or nuget restore?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I have a .Net Standard project in a solution and I want msbuild to build it on our build server.  If I do not run "nuget restore" first, I get the error "project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore".  I already have all of the necessary NuGet packages in the "packages" folder at the solution level.  I would like to indicate somehow that msbuild should just use the files in the local "packages" folder instead of trying to re-download the files.  How can I do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

.NET Standard projects do not use the `packages` folder in the solution. This is the "old" way of referencing NuGet packages through `packages.config`. The new way - `PackageReference` items in the project - uses a shared global packages folder in the user's home directory. The `project.assets.json` needs to be regenerated on the build machine with the resolved paths to this shared cache even if no packages need to be downloaded. In fact, a NuGet restore might not even need to hit the network if all packages are already on the machine.

Comment: Then, is there a way to indicate to Nuget Restore to use that "packages" folder at the solution level to refresh from?  My NuGet repository is privately shared on VSTS, and I don't know of a good way to store credentials with the build definitions, which are on a local TFS Server, not VSTS.

Comment: @Eric - I would take a look at using maybe the RestoreFallbackFolders  property which can be used to specify a folder the restore can look at when restoring NuGet packages - https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-NuGet-settings-in-MSBuild - or look at using a NuGet.Config file, contained with your solution, which has the package sources and credentials that you need.

Comment: also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687058/how-do-i-include-nuget-packages-in-my-solution-for-net-core-projects/43687514#43687514 - there are a few ways to include .nupkg files or the "global cache" in a git repo. But a global NuGet config on build agents can also specify feeds with credentials. And for VSTS there should be ways to let agents access feeds (don't know how exactly though)

Comment: But TL;DR the assets file and the generated .runtimeconfig.dev.json file (when you want to run tests) need to contain build machine specific paths in either ways - whether it would be `C:\Users\builduser\.nuget\packages` or `C:\agent\_work\2\s\checkedInGlobalCache`

Comment: @MartinUllrich what would you say, if I say this. command line to build solution fails (netstandard project with `PackageReference`). then, I open solution in IDE, `project.assets.json` is generated. Now I do nothing and close IDE. Re-run command line - works. so, back to original question, how to avoid restore/open IDE?

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I have come up with still involves a NuGet restore, but I added the local packages folder as one of the NuGet repositories in nuget.config and now I don't have to reach out to any remote repositories.  This is not quite what I wanted, but it is allowing me to progress.

```
  <packageSources>
    <add key="local" value=".\packages" />
  </packageSources>
```